# How to set sbt bin path in IntellIJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have a local sbt installed with a higher version. But the IntellIJ downloads a lower version of the sbt.

How/where can I update the path in the IntellIJ so that it takes up the newer version of sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | SBT |
> Launcher (sbt-launch.sbt)

As shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the settings?

Preferences
⇒ Build, Execution, Deployment
⇒ Build Tools
⇒ SBT

⇒ Launcher (sbt-launch.jar)
⇒ Custom

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ will use a built-in launcher which may be out of date, but the launcher automatically downloads a newer version of sbt if it is configured in your project's `project/build.properties` file, adding a line like this:

```
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

You can also choose a custom launcher binary in the Preferences: Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / SBT